# Error while installing app on ios7 - "app icon is disabled"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7

I have developed an app on iOS 6 with xcode 4.6. What I have done is I changed the old bundle identifier and changed app name. Also I have changed the flash screens. I have generated provisioning profile with new bundle identifier. Also I can make an archive of an app successfully. App is running fine on my simulator. But I am getting an error while installing the app on device. It is not getting installed. I am getting error as "**app icon is disabled**". The device's OS is iOS7. 
I am not getting what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: check you have added your device id in provisnl profile.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 yes. I have added it already.

Comment: what is your Architectures in Build Settings ?